# Test OpenGL ES matrix operations in console application Mac OS X

Tags: java, matrix, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

A console application to test matrix operations is not working because NetBeans cannot find `android.opengl.Matrix.*` as an import. Is there any way I can access methods like `setIdentityM` or `rotateM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Copied /Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-21/android/opengl/Matrix.java to a local package called android.opengl.  Better suggestions welcome.